# How to group multiple imageview to have 1 swipe gesture recognizer? IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

could anyone help me? I have this view with 5 UIImageView.

[image]

the default image in this 5 UIImageView is the `black star` 
I have attached tap and long press gesture recogniser to this 5 UIImageView

so in this case i tap the 3rd image then the other image behind them change to red star

it is like the normal rating scenario.

my question is how can I implement swipe gesture recogniser to this 5 UIImageView ?

can I group this 5 image into one and make 1 swipe gesture recogniser? is that possible?

could anyone help me how things like this get done? I appreciate anyones help. thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I finished the tap and long press gesture and its working fine. The only thing left to do is to add swipe.

Comment: my suggestion take 5 buttons use outletcollection or button tag with Single action method .

Answer (score 0):

I would use one image containing only the five stars and one squared image with red star and trasparent background color. Every time the user tap or swipe you can know wich stars is tapped using the location of the tap. Then according to which star has been pressed you place, n times ,the squared image with red star on top of the image containing the five black stars.